# Echoing Spaces Between a Hard-Coded Word and a Variable

Tags: php, html

For the code below, how could I put 5 spaces between "Submissions:" and `$row1["countSubmissions"]` ?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo '<td class="sitename5">Submissions: '.$row1["countSubmissions"].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Example:

`echo '<td class="sitename5">Submissions: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row1["countSubmissions"].'</td>';`

Comment: Between submissions and the variable. Using regular spaces will not work on an HTML page, you have to use `&nbsp;` instead.

Comment: They're HTML entities that represent spaces, you output them like any other character. So `echo "Submissions: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'`

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS - what you are probably doing belongs into the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PHP function `str_repeat`

You might also consider the CSS property `word-spacing`, which may be a better way to accomplish what you seem to be attempting.

Comment: He doesn't want to pad a string to a length, he literally wants five spaces at the end of the string